# Instead of printing to console create a dataframe for output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am currently comparing the text of one file to that of another file.
The method: for each row in the source text file, check each row in the compare text file.
If the word is present in the compare file then write the word and write 'present' next to it.
If the word is not present then write the word and write not_present next to it.
so far I can do this fine by printing to the console output as shown below:

```
import sys

filein = 'source.txt'
compare = 'compare.txt'
source = 'source.txt'

# change to lower case
with open(filein,'r+') as fopen:
    string = ""
    for line in fopen.readlines():
        string = string + line.lower()

with open(filein,'w') as fopen:
    fopen.write(string)

# search and list 
with open(compare) as f:
    searcher = f.read()

if not searcher:
    sys.exit("Could not read data :-(")

#search and output the results
with open(source) as f:
    for item in (line.strip() for line in f):
        if item in searcher:
            print(item, ',present')
        else:
            print(item, ',not_present')
```

the output looks like this:

```
dog ,present
cat ,present
mouse ,present
horse ,not_present
elephant ,present
pig ,present
```

what I would like is to put this into a pandas dataframe, preferably 2 columns, one for the word and the second for its state . I cant seem to get my head around doing this.

Comment: Create a Dict named Results, of form ```{'Name': ['dog', 'cat', ...], 'State':['Present', 'Present', ...]}.  Then use ```pd.DataFrame(Results)``` to create you dataframe

Comment: How would you do this if there was a large number of names? >1000

Comment: What is the format of source.txt and compare.txt?  Do you want the output to be in same order as compare.txt?  Why are you using sys.exit command?  Do you want to ignore punctuation such as dog == dog! or dog != dog!?  What do you want to do with the dataframe output once it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making several assumptions here to include:

1. Compare.txt is a text file consisting of a list of single words 1 word per line.
2. Source.txt is a free flowing text file, which includes multiple words per line and each word is separated by a space.
3. When comparing to determine if a compare word is in source, is is found if and only if, no punctuation marks (i.e. " ' , . ?, etc) are appended to the word in source .
4. The output dataframe will only contain the words found in compare.txt.
5. The final output is a printed version of the pandas dataframe.

With these assumptions:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
compare = 'compare.txt'
source = 'source.txt'

rslt = defaultdict(list)

def getCompareTxt(fid: str) -> list:
    clist = []
    with open(fid, 'r') as cmpFile:
        for line in cmpFile.readlines():
            clist.append(line.lower().strip('\n'))
    return clist    
    
cmpList = getCompareTxt(compare)
if cmpList:
    with open(source, 'r') as fsrc:
        items = []
        for item in (line.strip().split(' ') for line in fsrc):
            items.extend(item)
        
    print(items)
    for cmpItm in cmpList:
        rslt['Name'].append(cmpItm)
        if cmpItm in items:
            rslt['State'].append('Present')
        else:
            rslt['State'].append('Not Present')
                
    df = pd.DataFrame(rslt, index=range(len(cmpList))) 
    print(df)        
else:
    print('No compare data present')
```